# Is game world affected by the draw distance? (SMP)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For example, spawning of mobs, dissapearing of items, minecarts going by themselves, is any of that affected by the draw distance?

For example, obvisouly, the mobs do not spawn in the whole world (which is unlimited I guess), but only in some radius around you. Is that radius set statically, or does it depend on your render distance graphics setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is static -- no closer than 24 meters from the user, no farther than 144 meters.

To be crystal clear:

> `.` 8×4 meters area eligible for spawning
>   `X` Your position

```
....................................
....................................
....................................
....................................
....................................
....................................
.................. .................
..............         .............
.............           ............
............      X      ...........
.............           ............
..............         .............
.................. .................
....................................
....................................
....................................
....................................
....................................
```

I got the above, sans X, with

```
x = [["." if (i**2+j**2)>24**2 else " " for j in range(-72,72,4)]
                                        for i in range(-72,72,8)]
print "\n".join("".join(line) for line in x)
```

Comment: How do multiple players affect this?

Comment: Nice Python usage. But I have to ask if the spawn range is a 144-block *circle*, or square? :) I've never been clear on that.

Comment: @Cyclops The Minecraft wiki says it's a 144×144 square... wait, that means I made the square side twice as large than reqd. Whoops. Fixed.

Comment: @GnomeSlice I'd imagine each player has their own 144x144 block, so anything within any of those blocks would be active. It certainly wouldn't make sense from an efficiency standpoint to load any more than that, and if the blocks were reduced significantly, you'd have rendering issues as well as functionality issues with minecarts/redstone/etc.

Comment: Of course if two players were near each other, it would be an overlap of the two areas, so if they were right on top of each other, you'd only have ~21k blocks loaded instead of the ~41k blocks that would be loaded if they were far away from each other (assuming my theory is right).